# How can i change the marker of source and destination for the direction mode api of google

Tags: ios, google-maps, reactjs

I have rendered a map of google for plotting a route between source and destination using this api in react native for IOS application.

```
`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
?key=YOUR_API_KEY
&origin=Oslo+Norway
&destination=Telemark+Norway
&avoid=tolls|highways`
```

What I want is to change the custom marker for my start and end, only need a letter upon the marker.

Please help me with this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`suppressMarkers`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#DirectionsRenderer) option on the DirectionsRenderer to prevent the markers on the route from being displayed. You need to set the DirectionsDisplay's value to `TRUE`.

Here's a sample code snippet how to use suppressMarkers:

```
// Map and directions objects
var map = new google.maps.Map( element, options );
var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directions = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});

// Start/Finish icons
var icons = {
start: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
// URL
'start.png',
// (width,height)
new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
// The origin point (x,y)
new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
// The anchor point (x,y)
new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
),
end: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
// URL
'end.png',
// (width,height)
new google.maps.Size( 44, 32 ),
// The origin point (x,y)
new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
// The anchor point (x,y)
new google.maps.Point( 22, 32 )
)
};

service.route( { origin: origin, destination: destination }, function( response, status ) {
if ( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ) {
display.setDirections( response );
var leg = response.routes[ 0 ].legs[ 0 ];
makeMarker( leg.start_location, icons.start, "title" );
makeMarker( leg.end_location, icons.end, 'title' );
}
});
function makeMarker( position, icon, title ) {
new google.maps.Marker({
position: position,
map: map,
icon: icon,
title: title
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but its not something i am looking for, i am rendering google map using a webview in react native, i need a solution for that.